# Selenium IEDriver- Regarding PATH variable

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working on creating a regression test suite using Selenium for IE Browser. I am using the IEDriver exe from Selenium website. As per instructions from Selenium,

"The Internet Explorer Driver Server
This is required if you want to make use of the latest and greatest features of the WebDriver InternetExplorerDriver. Please make sure that this is available on your $PATH (or %PATH% on Windows) in order for the IE Driver to work as expected."

**Approach 1**
I tried to setup PATH variable via batch file as follows

```
setlocal
set varC=%CD%\ChromeDriver
set varI=%CD%\IEDriver
set PATH=%PATH%;%varC%;%varI%
```

However i still face issues with IEDriver not working properly.

**Approach 2**
When i set PATH variable via "Advanced System Settings", everything seems to be working fine. Can someone confirm if this setting can't be done via batch file or if i am performing some wrong operation?

Here is how I am initializing driver

```
    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void SetupTestFixture()
    {
        switch (ConfigPara.TestBrowser.ToLower())
        {
            case "ie":

                Utility.KillProcess("iexplore");
                DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer();
                caps.SetCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
                caps.SetCapability("nativeEvents", false);
                caps.SetCapability("allow-blocked-content", true);
                caps.SetCapability("disable-popup-blocking", true);
                caps.SetCapability("allowBlockedContent", true);
                aOptIE = new OpenQA.Selenium.IE.InternetExplorerOptions();
                aOptIE.InitialBrowserUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("baseURL");
                aOptIE.EnablePersistentHover = false;
                aOptIE.RequireWindowFocus = true;
                aOptIE.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;

                System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("webdriver.ie.driver", ConfigPara.IEDriverDirectory.FullName +"\\IEDriverServer.exe");
                Utility.Instance.driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ConfigPara.IEDriverDirectory.FullName, aOptIE);
                break;

        }

        Utility.Instance.driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7));

        baseURL = ConfigPara.BaseURL;
        Utility.Instance.wait = new OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait(Utility.Instance.driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        //utility = new Utility(driver);
    }

    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public void SetupTestTeardown()
    {
        try
        {
            Utility.Instance.driver.Quit();
            Utility.Instance.driver.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Ignore errors if unable to close the browser
        }

        Assert.AreEqual("", verificationErrors.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi actually you have to set the path of the IE driver that you downloaded form here http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/
please do it like below

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","pathofIEdriver\\IEDriverServer.exe");
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

Comment: N ish Ku Mar i did not notice this variable on the page you mentioned. Is this valid also for C# .NET?

Comment: plz follow http://www.joecolantonio.com/2012/07/31/getting-started-using-selenium-2-0-webdriver-for-ie-in-visual-studio-c/ for C#.NET hope this will help you

Comment: This did not help me as I already have same setup. My observation is that once IE driver crashes, it keeps crashing again and again. Hence i am not sure if it looks for any specific PATH while resetting IE driver

Answer (score 0):

User below code for C# webdriver:

```
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("webdriver.ie.driver", "Path\IEDriverServer.exe");
```

Comment: Didn't help improving the crashes. Performance is the same. Any other settings that i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use webdriver manager class to handle it.

```
WebDriverManager.iedriver().setup();
```

Added in your maven pom file :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

You can also use Webdrivermanage dependency for Gradle. This will automatically maintain IE driver exe file.